# Почему элемент, вложенный в defs нельзя вызвать из symbol?

Tags: svg

Почему элемент, вложенный в `defs` нельзя вызвать из `symbol`?

```html
<svg>  
<symbol id="a">
   <defs id="">
     <rect x="" y="" width="100" height="50" fill="" stroke="" stroke-width=""/>
  </defs>
</symbol>
<use xlink:href='#a' x='100' y='100' />     
</svg>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, что-то подозрительная правка заголовка...

Comment: @Qwertiy так теперь заголовок в точности отражает суть вопроса. Потом легче будет искать, а то у нас заголовки всегда носят очень неопределенный характер. Заглянешь в чатик? Вопрос есть

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, почему-то я подозреваю, что если правильно расставить атрибуты, то всё заработает и дело не во вложенности, а именно в использовании.

Comment: @Qwertiy В комментарий не вошло, сделал отдельный ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нарушена вложенность тегов, `<symbol id="a">` должен быть внутри `<defs></defs>`

```html
<svg>
 <defs>
  <symbol id="a">
      <rect width="100" height="50" fill="red" />
  </symbol>
</defs>
<use xlink:href='#a' />     
</svg>
```

Comment: я правильно понимаю что <symbol > может быть вложен в <defs> а наоборот нет ?

Comment: @Все что внутри <defs> - не рисуется, и <defs> должен быть в <svg>.

Comment: кажется я понял в чем проблема в <use> вызывается <symbol > т.к. в <symbol > вложен <defs>  в нем хранится содержимое оно и не показывается

Answer (score 3):

```html
 <svg>  
    
       <defs id="">
         <rect id="a" x="" y="" width="100" height="50" fill="" stroke="" stroke-width=""/>
      </defs>
    
    <symbol>
      <circle id="circ" cx="0" cy="0" r="20" />
    </symbol>
    
    <use xlink:href='#a' x='100' y='100' fill="red" />   
       <use xlink:href='#a' x='205' y='100' fill="dodgerblue" /> 
    
     <use xlink:href='#circ' x='100' y='50' fill="red" />   
       <use xlink:href='#circ' x='205' y='50' fill="dodgerblue" />
    
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Цитата из комментария

> почему-то я подозреваю, что если правильно расставить атрибуты, то всё
>   заработает и дело не во вложенности, а именно в использовании.

Всё может быть. Но лучше  не вкладывать `<defs>` в `<symbol>` по многим причинам:

Оба тега скрывают всё элементы находящееся внутри, так зачем же ещё усиливать это, вкладывая их друг в друга.

```html
<svg>  
<symbol id="a">
   <defs id="">
     <rect x="" y="" width="100" height="50" fill="" stroke="" stroke-width=""/>
  </defs>
</symbol>
<use xlink:href='#a' x='100' y='100' />     
</svg>
```

Кроме того  при вызове элементов наружу командой `<use>` они попадают в `shadow DOM` и , как известно, есть определенные трудности с их последующей стилизацией.

При такой схеме возможны варианты:

1. Стили определены в `<defs>`, который вложен в `<symbol>`
2. Стили определены в `<defs>`, который не вложен в `<symbol>`
3. Стили определены в `<defs>`, который не вложен в `<symbol>`, но к нему применены стили из `<defs>` и вся конструкция сохранена в спрайт - самостоятельный файл svg

[Вот пример](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44235845/7394871), демонстрирующий это вариант для разных браузеров:

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient">
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="black" />
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <symbol id="icon" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" fill="url(#gradient)" />
      </symbol>
    
      <use id="iconuse" xlink:href="#icon" width="100" height="100" />
    
    </svg>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Решение** в этом случае - применить стили не к `symbol`, а к вызывающей команде `<use>`

`<use class="iconuse" xlink:href="#rect" width="100" height="100" fill="url(#gradient)" />`

**Как видите варианты и их сочетания могут увеличиваться в геометрической прогрессии, что гарантирует получить неработающий SVG с трудно определяемой причиной.**

Обычно `<symbol>` используется для создания спрайтов SVG изображений

Технология такая – все иконки собираются в одном файле-шаблоне, при этом код каждой иконки упаковывается в свой отдельный символ с присвоением ему уникального идентификатора. Подробнее [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=1189).
С помощью изменения параметров `viewBox`ов в шапке SVG файла и в `symbol` масштабируется размер иконок. Ниже пример файла-шаблона. Этот способ удобен прежде всего тем, что прописав один раз уникальные идентификаторы по всему многостраничному проекту, в случае необходимости не нужно править везде. Иконки можно заменять, редактировать, изменяя код файла шаблона. Полная аналогия с CSS.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1" 
width="450" height="450"  viewBox="0 0 1100 1100"  >
 
  <symbol id="window-domain" viewBox="0 0 3300 3300" >
    <title>icon window-domain </title>
    <desc> below code icons - "window-domain" </desc>
       <path d=.... />
  </symbol>
     <symbol id="internet-speed" viewBox="0 0 3300 3300" >
          <title>icon internet-speed </title>
           <desc> below code icons - "internet-speed" </desc>
                  <path d=.... />
     </symbol>
          <symbol id="secure-ssl" viewBox="0 0 3300 3300">
            <title>icon isecure-ssl </title>
             <desc> below code icons - "secure-ssl" </desc>
                  <path d=.... />
           </symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: Я просто перенёс id: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4ARx.png